# XML structure wit labels

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

Hi i am new into programming i was creating a xml schema i know its very basic but still i am not able to fix i am create a employee xml schema as

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <Name>Frank abc</Name>
    <AccountNumber>22233</AccountNumber>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

It will print

```
Frank abc]]
22233
```

It works fine but what to do if i want to add labels such as

```
Name: Frank abc
Account :22233
```

Help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: That's not a schema.  That's just a document.  What is it you're trying to do exactly?  And what language are you working with to do the printing?

Comment: i am sorry i need to create a simple xml document and it works fine but what if need to add a label is there any keyword to do it?

Comment: In general, no, there isn't.  If you're writing a program to process this specific document, the program could add these labels itself, since it knows what it's about to print.  If you're just displaying this in a browser, then that's another matter.  How are you "printing" the document?

Comment: i want to print like this Name: Frank abc
Account :22233  then have to add css on label and data

Comment: How you go about doing this is heavily dependent on what technology you want to use to transform this document into output.  You have many options.  Is your intent to just load this document in a web browser directly and have it display nicely, or will you be doing further processing?

Comment: I see that this is also tagged with xmlhttprequest.  Is this XML being sent back by a web server and then processed with JavaScript?